# React - Apply **active** class to an element using CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, module

I'm diving into React and I found a little problem managing *active* class names when using CSS modules.

Suppose I want to develop a Tabs React component. I would like to apply an *active* class to the current list item. The tab headers is built by the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Tabs.scss';

export default class TabHeader extends Component {

    render() {
        let activeTabIndex = this.props.activeTabIndex;

        return (
            <ul className={styles['tabs-header']}>
                {
                    this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <a className={(index === activeTabIndex) ? 'active' : ''} href="#">
                                    <span>{item.header}</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, I conditionally added the class *active* to the interested list item. The stylesheet code is Tabs.scss:

```
.tabs-header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;

    & li {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ECF0F1;
        cursor: pointer;

        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #212F3D;
            transition: all .2s ease-in;
            transform: skew(-40deg);

            &:hover {
                background: #2471A3;
                color: #F7F9F9;
            }

            & span {
                display: block;
                transform: skew(40deg);
            }

            &.active {
                background: #2471A3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, the active item is not using the *active* css code. How can I solve the problem?

EDIT: the prop `activeTabIndex` (integer greater than or equal to zero)  is correctly working. If I inspect the elements, I can see the class `active` being added to the active item list, but it is not pointing to the class defined in Tabs.scss. Just to point this out, when using `className={styles['tabs-header']}` in the `ul` element, this is going to be converted to `Tabs__tabs-header__2LSPG`.

Comment: have you checked that `activeTabIndex` is defined and equal to `0` ?

Comment: make you what kind of value `activeTabIndex` have? then check your condition `(index === activeTabIndex) ? 'active' : 'usingElseClassHere'`. I hope, you should fix that.

Comment: Is `this.props.activeTabIndex` definitely a number, not a string? Try `(index === Number(activeTabIndex))` to force to an integer maybe?

Comment: @Toby , @YouneL , @Ikram - Ud - Daula I added an edit to specify what `activeTabIndex` is.

Comment: Is *any* of the css being applied?

Comment: @Toby, all the css are being applied, exept `active`!

Comment: Your css/sass looks correct. Might be worth recreating at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard) so we can troubleshoot with actual code..

Comment: @Toby, I've never used CodeSandbox before: at the moment I have no idea how to enable the SCSS. Anyway, [here is the project](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw4792wp2q).

Comment: scss works  by default, I'm not sure about css-modules. Here is a CodeSandbox with React and css-modules: https://codesandbox.io/s/k305yn11n7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’d need to try it out to be confident of this, but I think you should be using `styles.active` instead of `'active’`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I wonder, what would happen if my css module would have two or more `active` class for different elements?

Answer (score 1):

this should work<a
className={`${index === activeTabIndex && css.active}`}
href="#"

> {item.header}

Answer (score 1):

All about CSS modules in React: 
For a className with the dash use: **style["upper-level"]** 
Single word className: **style.active** 
To combine a multiple classNames use: **style["upper-level"] + " " + style.active**

```
import style from "./style.module.css";
...
className={
            menuOpened
              ? style["upper-level"] + " " + style.active
              : style["upper-level"]
          }
```

Comment: I had a css classname that i had to apply "active" to. Your answer to combine multiple classNames has saved me a lot of time. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, i guess it will work

```
className={(index === activeTabIndex) ? styles.active: ''}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your condition would leave an empty space in a class name because of the condition:

```
(index === activeTabIndex) ? 'active' : ''
```

Instead you can do a short-circuit evaluation:

```
<a className={(index === activeTabIndex) && styles['active']} href="#">
  <span>{item.header}</span>
</a>
```